# Positioning an element relative to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm making a plugin that makes a dropdown on an element and use a pre-defined element as the dropdown menu outside the applied element.

The markup looks like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="some-menu" data-dropdown="dropdown-element">Click</a>

<ul id="dropdown-element">
    <li><a href="#">First item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second item</a></li>
</ul>
```

And using `$("#some-menu").dropdown({ placement: 'top' });` will turn `#dropdown-element` to a dropdown. All good and dandy.

`placement` decides on how the dropdown is positioned according to the element *(top, bottom, right, left)* but this should be fairly easy to apply, when I have figured the default positioning out.

I tried using this code from Bootstrap's Tooltip plugin

```
pos = getPosition($element, inside);

actualWidth = $this[0].offsetWidth;
actualHeight = $this[0].offsetHeight;

switch (inside ? placement.split(' ')[1] : placement) {
    case 'bottom':
        tp = {top: pos.top + pos.height, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2};
    break;
    case 'top':
        tp = {top: pos.top - actualHeight, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2};
    break;
    case 'left':
        tp = {top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left - actualWidth};
    break;
    case 'right':
        tp = {top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left + pos.width};
    break;
}
```

But without luck.

This is what it looks like
[image: How the dropdown looks like in browser]

And this is the wanted result
[image: How the dropdown should look like]

I want it horizontally centered to `#some-menu` and the dropdown to be applied to any element, inlines too and keep both the vertical and horizontal positioning.

**Edit:**
I found out that the dropdown was created inside a element with `position: relative`, which is why its offset is wrong. My question is now what the best way to move the element into the body (or perhaps a better solution for this) and keep good performance without touching the DOM more than needed.

Comment: +1 for the question. Also, nice diagram but can you add one for what you want it to look like too? Unless I've misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

This should put the menu in the center.

```
top = $('#some-menu').offset().top + 8; //Set the vertical position.

left = $('#some-menu').offset().left - $('#dropdown-element').outerWidth/2 + $('#some-menu').outerWidth/2; //Set the menu to the center of the button.

$('#dropdown-element').offset({top: top, left: left});
```

Comment: The dropdown is not a child of the button, but should still be relative to the buttons position. However, the real problem I have is to make the real math on how to do this.